# Angular Animation causing DOM Leak

Tags: angular, animation, angular5, angular-animations

I am using Angular animations for the first time and am currently running into an memory leak. After removing the animations from the template / component, there are no detached DOM elements anymore.

What i am trying to accomplish is an animated list (list items flying in from the right).

So i have set up the animations like this:

```
animations: [
  trigger('itemList', [
    transition('0 => *', [
      query('li', style({ transform: 'translateX(+200%)', opacity: 0 }), { optional: true }),
      query('li',
        stagger('400ms', [
          animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)', opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        { optional: true }
      )
    ])
  ])
]
```

And my template basically looks like this:

```
<ul id="item-list" [@itemList]="items.length">
  <li class="row" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <app-list-item [item]="item"></app-list-item>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The animation actually does work, but as soon as the list get's updated (changes within the itemlist) i have detached DOM Elements.

As i said, it's the first time i am using Angular Animations (v5.0.0) so there might be some general setup issue but i simply can't find it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: hi! just a quick question: what exactly do u mean by 'causing Memory Leak' ?

Comment: as soon the list changes and the view get's updated i have a lot of detached DOM elements. After removing the animation from the component, and try again, there are no more detached elements. So i figured it must be related to the animations

Comment: I wonder if you could reproduce the issue into a Plunker. I think it will to help a clarify the problem